# Selection probabilty of an item

Tags: probability

I have a problem that need to solve that is related with probability. I have a test case that can be failed or pass in each run. So the outcome could be $0$ or $1$ only.

I have ten observation that means $1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1$ . So we see in second and seventh run the test case failed. So How can I predict the test case that pass/fail in next run? which probability theory I can use for these?

Comment: I am assuming this is a random sample, and you will run another random sample through, and want a prediction about the number of fails. Too little information for anything reliable.

Comment: This seems like a complicated problem.  You could use the binomial distribution and assume that the probability of success is $\frac{8}{10} = 0.80$, but I think that's too simplistic.  Also, do you know whether or not each test is independent of the last?  If not, then this isn't truly a binomial distribution.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I assume that each test case is independent.

Comment: @Jared , I assume that each test is independent of the last excution.

Comment: If we are sampling independently, then the number of successes in a sample of $10$ has binomial distribution. However, a sample size of $10$ is not enough to estimate the parameter $p$ (probability of success in a trial) with enough precision to make reliable predictions about another random sample of $10$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas lets say I have 40 sample to predict the outcome of 41th run?

Comment: So $400$ data points? The number of successes in a run of $10$ still has too large a variance for a useful $95\%$ confidence interval. But you can estimate $p$ not too badly, using the normal approximation to the binomial (unless the probability of success is near $0$ or near $1$, but then there are other techniques).

Answer (score 0):

If we assume a [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) then the particular order you got isn't important.  The probability of getting two successes out of ten would be:

$$
p(2\text{ successes}) = \binom{10}{2}p^8\left(1 - p\right)^2
$$

We can find the $p$ which maximizes this probability (and I would guess, up front, that would be $p = .8$).  We only need to maximize the following function since $\binom{10}{2}$ is a constant:

$$
f(p) = p^8(1 - p)^2 \\
f'(p) = 8p^7(1 - p)^2 - 2p^8(1 - p)
$$

Set this to zero to find critical points--factor out $2p^7(1 - p)$:

$$
2p(1 - p)^2\left(4(1 - p) - p\right) = 0 \\
2p(1 - p)^2\left(4 - 4p - p\right) = 0 \\
2p(1 - p)^2(4 - 5p) = 0
$$

Indeed we get critical points of $p = 0$, $p = 1$, and $p = \frac{4}{5} = 0.8$.  The first two give the minimums of $0$ and the $p = 0.8$ gives the maximum.

Therefore, if these *are* independent events then, most likely, based on the data, the probability of success is $p = 0.8$.

*Note: There are [statistical tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_significance#Role_in_statistical_hypothesis_testing) you can do to determine the likelihood that $p = 0.8$ is correct.*

Comment: thanks for your reply. As my idea is to predict for 11th run of the test case. Lets say I run the test case for 40 times. So I want to predict the outcome in 41th run where it will be pass/fail (1/0).